# How to create normal texture with node setup?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals

My question is pretty simple. How do I create a normal texture by combining certain nodes with the diffuse texture? This would be really helpful and would save me LOADS of time! Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like the Bump node?

Comment: For a good explanation, have a look at the link here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7PQGgz1RII

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your model
2. Add a material to it
3. Open a view and select node editor
4. You'll see your material initial setup
5. Add an image
6. Add an texture / image texture node and assign your image to it. **Make sure to keep this node selected for the bake below**
7. Go to the render panel
8. Select normal and click on "bake"

[image]

You can also bake bump maps, here is a example using a noise texture :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

RGB Normal maps are somewhat difficult to generate on the fly.  Instead, as others have suggested, you can extract normal information from a bump node.

[image: bumpNode]

Why a bump node?

Bump nodes interpret height information (where white is high and black is low) and converts it to a normal deformation for cycles.  The fact that the input is Black and White means that it is fairly trivial to draw or even generate your input texture.  All that then has to happen is that the normal output must be connected to the shader's normal input.

[image: simpleBumpSetup]