# High poly mesh slow in blender?

Tags: animation

trying to animate highpoly mesh about 1 million polygons even slower when I try to apply physics like softbodies is there a way around this?seems like I really got to lower the polygons in order to run smooth.

Comment: Are you aware of the technique of generating a normalmap from a highpoly model and applying it to a lowpoly version of the same model?

Comment: Looks like you'll have to retopologize your model to make the topology less dense and then bake normals from the high poly model to the low poly one. Search for RETOPOLOGY and BAKING NORMALS tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may ***retopologize*** your model and then ***bake normals*** from the high poly model to the low poly one. This will save all the details but the geometry won't be as dense, so it will be more animation friendly.
[image]

First you have to ***retopologize*** your high poly model (take a look at these answers: [How to easily make mesh retopology?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology) and [How to convert from high poly to low poly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly)).
There are two models pictured below. The high poly one with a very dense geometry on the left and low poly one with a simple retopologized geometry on the right. With your retopologized model you'll be able to bake the details from the high poly model to the low poly one. 
[image]

Here's how to do it. First unwrap your low poly mesh and create a new texture with the desired parameters. 
[image]

Next select (with the <kbd>RMB</kbd>) the high poly model, then select the low poly one.
[image]

Go to *Render* data header and under ***Bake*** panel change the mode to ***Normals***, check the ***Selected to Active*** checkbox, then press the ***Bake*** button. After Blender finishes baking save the image to your computer.
[image]

Now give your low poly model a material, go to *Texture* header, open your previously saved image and set the settings as pictured below.
[image]

To see the normal map in action change the *viewport shading type* to ***Rendered*** and set the ***GLSL*** option in the *Shading* panel of Properties Shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: I showed the normal map baking in Blender Render engine. If you want to do it in Cycles engine please check out this topic: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55680/how-to-create-normal-texture-with-node-setup

Comment: now I have a better understanding thank you for taking the time and explaining it.