# How to generate fake Normal map from an image texture inside Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image, normal-map

Back in a day when I worked with Blender Internal render exclusievely there was a slider called Normals, I simply cranked it up and the texture started to look voluminous. Struggled to find the same thing in Cycles.Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think the bump node is what you want?

Plug the BW output of the image into the hight input of the bump node. Then, feed the bump node's normal output into the normal input(s) of your shader. You can also plug raw BW images into the displacement input of the Material Output. For more reading on the bump node, check this out: [How to create normal texture with node setup?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55680/how-to-create-normal-texture-with-node-setup)

Comment: I discovered  bump node but somehow couldn`t get anything from it. Guess my setup was wrong. Gonna try soon , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, there are third party apps such as these: https://www.slant.co/topics/4757/~programs-for-making-height-maps-normal-maps-and-or-other-maps#1

I have personally used CrazyBump, and although it seems sketchy, I can confirm that it works. If you use one of these, you have to load in your color (albedo) texture, and it will generate a normal map. You can then load the normal map into blender, and use a normal map node to control its intensity. A bit of a hassle, but this gets the best results that I know of.

Comment: Thanks! Some programs are new to me in that list

Comment: You have to use Normal maps with the Normal node, and Displacement maps with the Bump node: Create the Normal or Displacement image with a soft like CrazyBump, import it in an Image Texture node, plug this node into a Normal or Bump node, and plug this node into the Normal input of the nodes you want (Glossy, Diffuse...)